# Push a subroutine with argument into a stack in Perl

Tags: perl, subroutine, perl-data-structures

I would like to push a subroutine **with arguments** into a stack, but I can't figure out the syntax. Consider a working example with no arguments:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

sub hi    { print "hi\n";    }
sub hello { print "hello\n"; }
sub world { print "world\n"; }

my @stack;
push (@stack, \&hi   );
push (@stack, \&hello);
push (@stack, \&world);

while (@stack) {
    my $proc = pop @stack;
    $proc->();
}
```

when I run the code:

```sh
% ./pop-proc.pl
world
hello
hi
```

Now my question is, what if the subroutine looked like this:

```perl
sub mysub 
{
    chomp( my( $arg ) = @_ );
    print "$arg\n"; 
}
```

and I'd like to push subroutines with arguments, such as:

```perl
mysub("hello");
mysub("world");
```

your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: `&$proc` means something very special. You mean to use `&$proc()` or the clearer `$proc->()`.

Comment: Thank you @ikegami. I have modified my sample code as per your suggestion to use `$proc->()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an anonymous sub (which may even be a closure).

```
push @stack, sub { mysub("hello") };
push @stack, sub { mysub("world") };
```

For example,

```
sub hi { say "@_" }
my $arg = "Hello";
my $sub = sub { hi($arg, @_) };
$sub->("World");   # Hello World
```

Answer (score 8):

I might do something like this where I create a tuple to hold the code reference and its arguments:

```
use v5.24;

sub hi    { print "Hi @_\n";    }
sub hello { print "Hello @_\n"; }

my @stack;
push @stack, [ \&hi,    'Perl'     ];
push @stack, [ \&hello, 'Amelia'   ];
push @stack, [ \&hello, $ENV{USER} ];

while (@stack) {
    my( $proc, @args ) = pop( @stack )->@*;
    $proc->( @args );
}
```

I use the v5.24 [postfix dereference](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) there, but that's because I can't help myself. This works too but now I think it's very ugly:

```
    my( $proc, @args ) = @{ pop( @stack ) };
```

Comment: Replace `use v5.24;` with `use feature qw( postderef );  # 5.20+` and `no warnings qw( experimental::postderef );  # No longer experimental as of 5.24` and your code will run in 5.20+